# React Native Horizontal ScrollView is way wider than the image it contains

Tags: react-native, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I want to have a ScrollView containing an Image. The image is like 16000px x 10000. I'd like the image's height to be the screens height on initial position and the width to be scrollable.

I managed to get the image to fill the screen's height but for some reason, it's way too much scrollable (like 3 times the screen width, whereas the actual image is like 1.8 times the screen width). What can I do to get rid of the extra blank space around my Image ?

Also, how do I then make the image zoomable (and therefore, make the image scroll vertically as well as horizontally)

The goal here is to have a zoomable map but with custom background, so I can't use react-native-maps (unless I missed something ?)

```
class ScrollTest extends Component {
    render(){
        let height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <ScrollView horizontal>
                        <Image
                            resizeMode='contain' 
                            source={require('./assets/scrolltest.jpg')}
                            style={{height}}
                        />
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: with custom background do you mean backgoundcolor ? or an image?

Comment: a 16000x10000 px image???

Comment: I mean an image and the way too large dimensions are just for testing purposes, making sure the height adjusts to actual screen height